# How to fix ceiling which squeaks when door is opened

Tags: doors, ceiling, noise

The ceiling in my bedroom creaks when I open and close the bedroom door which is annoying. Is there any way to easily stop this from happening?

Comment: I moved the comment to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never had or heard of this happening before, but it sounds like the framing needs to be tightened up somewhere. The squeak will need to be isolated, as in pinpointed to the actual joint or where 2 pieces of wood come together, is squeaking, then with some care, screw the framing together so it draws the joint where the framing meets is tight again.